# LINQ fastest way to update lots of records (>2m)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have this loop:

```
using(var db = new MainContext())
{
    var q = db.tblInternalURLs;
    foreach (var rec in q)
    {
        db.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE tblInternalURLS SET hash = '" + LoginAPI.GetSha1(rec.URL) + "' WHERE ID = " + rec.ID);
    }
}
```

Converting the update query to `db.ExecuteCommand` has improved speed considerably, however I was wondering if there's a faster way to execute these queries as it still takes a long time over 2,000,000+ records.  I believe a lot of the overhead is in the initial LINQ query. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what is `tblInternalURLs`. If you can write it with one SQL command, Yes, it can be improved, otherwise No.

Comment: you could probably replace `var q = db.tblInternalURLs;` with a faster select clause ... it'd be interesting to see what the hivemind come's up with ...

Comment: If thats just an iteration over a sql server table table how about `UPDATE tblInternalURLS SET hash = hashbytes('sha1', url)`

Comment: @Xander That's why it's a comment, not an answer.  It's perfectly appropriate as a comment, and very much worth doing.

Comment: @Servy i hope this question isn't being downvoted because of it ...

Comment: Is there any benifit of using a `MainContext` rather than using the raw `SqlConnection/SqlCommand` classes (and then re-using the connection throughout the loop)?

Comment: @Xander I wouldn't think so.  More likely because questions of the form, "Here's some code, make it faster" aren't particularly high quality questions.  In this case there isn't a whole lot of context, there's no metrics for how fast it is, and how fast it needs to be, performance in general is also very hardware/environment/context dependent, unlike so many other programming problems.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do the hashing in code and not on the server?

Answer (score 10):

Well, seeing as SQL Server supports hashing, you could avoid taking any data to the client by writing a SQL query to do the whole table in one go:

```
update 
 tblInternalURLS 
SET 
 hash = HASHBYTES('SHA1',CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), URL))
```

If the hash is stored as a string, `sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring` might be handy.

Comment: it's worth stating explicitly that this approach removes the need to iterate the 2mm rows in your program altogether

Comment: this has got to run much faster overall but will be more likely to deadlock.

Comment: @Jodrell, I would ask that you explain how this could cause a deadlock

Comment: @gunr2171 Why would a `where` statement be required? OP is iterating entire table and generating updates for ***every*** row. As such, the `update` in my answer doesn't need constraining.

Comment: @gunr2171, maybe not deadlock but certainly conflict. If I change all 2x10^6 records at once in 1 transaction, and some other transaction wants to alter one or more hash values during that processing then a collision will occur. If you commit the changes one row or page at a time a collision is less likely. So there is a tradeoff but it is only relavent is there could be concurrent alterations to any hash value.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be faster since it's limiting the `select` to only return the columns that are needed.

Change:

```
var q = db.tblInternalURLs;
```

To:

```
var q = db.tblInternalURLs.Select(x => new { URL = x.URL, ID = x.ID }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster way will be in using native ADO.NET Prepare command and then bind parameters instead of concat query strings and produce many different queries (from DB point of view).
Each new query must be parsed by server...

Here is the snippet

```
var conn = ...//get native connection from your context
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblInternalURLS SET hash = @hash WHERE ID = @id";

var hashParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
//set parameter type and name

 var idParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
//set parameter type and name

cmd.Parameters.Add(hashParam);
cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);

//prepare command
cmd.Prepare();

 foreach (var rec in q)
 {
     idParam.Value = rec.ID;
     hashParam.Value =  LoginAPI.GetSha1(rec.URL);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 }
```

**Update**
If you are using SQL Server and the hash column must be always in sync with URL, then you could modify tblInternalURLS table and convert hash column to *computed* column. In this case the hash column will be always in sync with URL.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblInternalURLS DROP COLUMN hash

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblInternalURLS 
 ADD hash AS 
 CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA1', URL) AS VARBINARY(20)) PERSISTED
```

Comment: You might want to turn the `conn` object into a `using` so that it auto-closes and disposes itself.

Comment: I beleave that connection will be closed/returned to pool by outer linq context. But in other case I would wrap **conn** by **using**.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest paginating your query.  Right now you're pulling all 2,000,000 records in all at once.  That's a drain on the DB, on the network connection, on the memory of your client, etc.

By breaking that up into several smaller queries each grabbing pages of, say, a few thousand, you'll potentially see some noticeable improvements.

Here are a few helpers to paginate a given query:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int pageSize)
{
    return GetPages(query, pageSize).SelectMany(x => x);
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPages<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int pageSize)
{
    for (int currentPage = 0; true; currentPage++)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> nextPage = query.Skip(currentPage * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();

        if (nextPage.Any())
            yield return nextPage;
        else
            yield break;
    }
}
```

If you add a call to `Paginate(1000)` to your query you should see at least some improvement.